# Azure web app key vault exception when recycled

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

We have several ASP.NET Core web apps that use the Azure Key Vault.

This works well through all manual restarts, but when the web app is recycled automatically by Azure it does not start successfully due to a "KeyVaultErrorException: Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service".

Restarting manually then works correctly. We have appinitialization turned on.

I realize that multiple instances would mitigate this, but how can we have the app successfully restart when recycled by Azure?

Edit:
The key vault is setup using the "Add connected services" through Visual Studio 2019, via the Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup package v2.0.4

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample of how you instantiate a `KeyVaultClient` and where in your application lifecycle you do it. Also, the Azure SDK team recommends you upgrade to the newer packages - e.g. Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets - where active development is done. They are faster, reduce memory allocations, easier to diagnose, and easier to customize. See https://aka.ms/azsdk/intro for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the keyvault in the portal -> `Networking`, make sure you select the `Allow access from All networks`.

Or if you select the `Private endpoint and selected networks`, try to add all the `Additional Outbound IP Addresses` to the firewall.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the vault from being accessed by all networks for security reasons - is that valid?

I can add the additional outbound IP addresses, but I'm curious as to why it would work in all situations except for an Azure-triggered recycle?

Comment: @user704772 Maybe you select the `Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall`? If so, because the azure web is not a trusted service.

Comment: I have that selected - I also should've noted that I have virtual networks allowed, which the apps belong to.